# jQuery keyUp/AJAX get combo always 1 or 2 strokes behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I built a [very simple Twitter Instant Search](http://crowdlistr.com/instant) for fun, using jQuery and PHP. I bind an event to keyup on the search form, and make a quick AJAX call to a PHP page that curls Twitter Search JSON.

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('#search').bind('keyup', function(){
  var v = $('#search').val();
  console.log(v);
  $.get('get.php',{q: v, a:''}, function(data){
   obj = {};
   window.tw = '';
    obj = eval('('+ data +')');
  if(typeof obj.results.length !== undefined){
    for (var i=0; i < obj.results.length; i++) {
     tw += '<div class="tweet"><h2><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+obj.results[i].from_user+'">@'  + obj.results[i].from_user + '</a></h2> <span>' + obj.results[i].text + '</span><' + '/div>';
    };
    }
   });
 $('#container').html(window.tw);  
 });

});
</script>
```

Even though the console.log value returned is right, it still falls behind 1-2 characters, in terms of the results it displays. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: For the JSON aspect, you can use the function `$.getJSON` instead, and the return value will be a JSON object by default.  Also, for parsing anywhere, instead of using `eval`, you can use the `$.parseJSON` function and get rid of the need to add the parentheses.

Comment: @Zurahn yeah, you're totally right; but I wrote this in a cab, and so didn't have access to jQuery documentation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#container').html(window.tw);
```

This should be inside the callback given to $.get()

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').bind('keyup', function(){
        var v = $('#search').val();
        console.log(v);
        $.get('get.php',{q: v, a:''}, function(data){
            obj = {};
            window.tw = '';
                        obj = eval('('+ data +')');
                        if(typeof obj.results.length !== undefined){
                for (var i=0; i < obj.results.length; i++) {
                    tw += '<div class="tweet"><h2><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+obj.results[i].from_user+'">@'  + obj.results[i].from_user + '</a></h2> <span>' + obj.results[i].text + '</span><' + '/div>';
                };
            }
            $('#container').html(window.tw);    
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're sending out the AJAX request immediately. Once you do that, the code becomes asynchronous, meaning it can come back in any order depending on latency. If the results return the original search term, you could perform a match on to make sure the returned results still match what's in the search box.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it; in fact, seems to break it even further   if(obj.query==$('#search').val() ) now it shows results even more sporadically

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem isn't in the get.php part of the process?

**edit**

Ah, I think I spotted the problem.  I think the call to

```
 $('#container').html(window.tw);
```

Needs to be in the $.get success callback, not in the keyup event function - as it is, that fires before the $.get has returned anything so it's showing the last set of responses instead.  A single letter search doesn't return any results.

Comment: Pretty sure; when I inspect the AJAX calls, they all have properly formed JSON (for the correct query) being returned.

Comment: Your edit is right, but @letonje beat you to the right answer by a minute.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as soon as I hit submit, guess I need to type faster :)